# github multiple accounts error

Tags: git, github

I have set up multiple account according to [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574).

One account is git/myname1 and another is git/myname2

When I push I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Permission to myname2/myrepo.wiki.git denied to myname1.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I added my user name to local git.

```
[user]
    name = myname1
```

But it still give the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are aware of the GitHub terms “One person or legal entity may not maintain more than one free account.”? Apart of that: Did you verify that the remote is the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration `user.name` only applies to commits you create. This is a Git setting and does not affect the login for GitHub.

Please check step 3 and 4 of your tutorial again where it tells you how to configure a separate SSH key for your other user and define a new server address for GitHub using that SSH key.

In general though, having multiple accounts on GitHub is neither useful nor adviced. If you need some separation for different purposes, set up organizations. For example if your employer wants you to contribute to their projects on GitHub, make them invite your *personal* account into their organization account so you can contribute with just a single account.

Comment: I think it's useful to have separate accounts for personal and professional use. If my home computer gets compromised, that should not give an attacker access to company source-code. I know it's technically against the ToS, but I don't think GitHub cares too much.

Comment: @CodesInChaos That’s a bad argument. If your home computer gets compromised, you should revoke access for its SSH key (since you are using separate keys for *every* machine you access from). Also, since you always protect your SSH keys using a passphrase, your home computer being compromised does not give anyone access to your repositories.

Comment: Using separate SSH keys is all nice and well, but it doesn't protect against a compromised home computer. Since 1) The github password will leak once I log into the website the next time on the compromised machine, giving access to everything 2) The SSH key on the home computer can still access repositories in the organization account. 3) The passphrase doesn't help, since the trojan/key-logger can steal it on next entry just like it can steal the key itself. 4) To revoke I need to know that I was compromised. You don't notice that unless the attacker is incompetent or a small time criminal.